# An episode of a TV series, late 60s early 70s l think

Tags: story-identification, tv, spaceship, space-colonization

Huge rocket ship carrying humans to a distant destination to resettle. The bridge of the craft is inaccessible except for a tube where food is sent up. The passengers revere "the tree".

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 9):

The 1978 [*Doctor Who* story "Underworld"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld_(Doctor_Who)) features a generation ship, the P7E where most of the crew—and eventually their descendants—were enslaved and provide food and fuel to the controlling entity on the bridge of the ship, which is accessed via a vertical shaft.

Per Wikipedia:

> Most of the population live as slaves digging rock for fuel and sustenance, but they are culled and killed in rock collapses called Skyfalls. This situation is overseen by guards who are in turn responsible to two robots called Seers. In overall control is the Oracle, a powerful super-computer which has shaped the perverse society. Evidently the P7E became trapped in the planet millennia earlier and the entire basis of the mission was lost over time. The Doctor and Leela encounter Idas, a young man nearly killed in a Skyfall, learning how the local population is managed and terrorised. The Seers and Oracle exist in a protected Citadel at the heart of the planetoid (clearly the P7E) and the Doctor, Leela and Idas venture there, in the process rescuing Idas’ father Idmon who was due to be sacrificed to the Oracle. Other slaves are freed too, and flee to the R1C where Jackson makes them welcome. However, the crucial race banks remain in the control of the Oracle. The Doctor, Leela, and Idas venture to the Citadel again to get the precious cargo.

Not having watched this episode recently when I wrote this answer originally, I had forgotten that the transportation shaft system is indeed known to the descendants a "the Tree."  Use of the the Tree is limited to the caste of Seers, the inner circle of (robotic) servants of the Oracle (the P7E's now-mad computer).

> **DOCTOR:** Recognise that?
> **IDAS:**  The Tree.  We call it "the Tree".
> **DOCTOR:**  The Tree at the End of the World.  Where are we?
> **IDAS:**  Here.
> **DOCTOR:**  Where's your father?  I see.  Can we get from there to there quickly?
> **IDAS:**  No.
> **DOCTOR:**  Why not?
> **IDAS:**  It's forbidden.
> **DOCTOR:**  Why?
> **IDAS:**  It's guarded by invisible dragons.  Not even the guards can use it, only Seers.  They have special powers.
> **DOCTOR:**  So do I, Idas.  So do I.  The Tree at the End of the World's always guarded by dragons.  They're fire dragons, aren't they, with tongues of flame?